# How to reduce the equation to get the ratio of a/b

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to reduce an equation to get a ratio, x/y.\\\
The equation is as following (a,b,...,j are known numbers):

```
1.5*a*Log[
    b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y]*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(d*x + 
     i*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) + 
  2.5*a*Log[
    e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y]*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(d*x + 
     i*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - 
  4*a*Log[d*x + i*y]*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + 
     j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - 
  0.5*(b*x + c*y)*
   Log[b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + 
     j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - (b*x + c*y)*
   Log[a*x + g*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - 
  1.5*(b*x + c*y)*
   Log[e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + 
     j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) + 
  3*(b*x + c*y) Log[
    d*x + i*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - 
  2.5*d*Log[
    b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(d*x + i*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 
     2*f*x*y) + 
  4*d*Log[a*x + g*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(e*x^2 + 
     j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) - 
  1.5*d*Log[
    e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 
     2*x*y)*(e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y) + 
  1.5*(e*x + f*y)*
   Log[b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 
     2*c*x*y)*(d*x + i*y) - 
  3*(e*x + f*y)*
   Log[a*x + g*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(d*x + i*y) + 
  0.5*(e*x + f*y)*
   Log[e*x^2 + j*y^2 + 2*f*x*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 
     2*c*x*y)*(d*x + i*y) + (e*x + f*y) Log[
    d*x + i*y]*(a*x + g*y)*(b*x^2 + h*y^2 + 2*c*x*y)*(d*x + i*y) == 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: If the values are known, give them.

Comment: I would define r==x/y and use the replacement x goes to y r. However, I can't find a solution with any techniques I know. I suspect that any fully symbolic answer will be unobtainable or too complicated to be useful.

Comment: I went for replacing `x` with `k y` and tried to solve k out, but Mathematica cannot solve it easily.

Comment: I am trying to use Mathmatica to simply the equation to get the ratio of x/y

Comment: The values a, b, ..., j are not fixed. I would like to change the values in different senarios.